# How can I delete my account?

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

Can someone please delete my account? I can't find an option to do so

I tried going to the settings and looking for an option but I can't find one

Comment: In the previous question you posted you were given this link in a comment: [Delete My Account](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9456/delete-my-account). You can find instructions there. However, maybe you could reconsider (or at least think about it for a while) before doing such decision. From my own experience I can say that this site can be very useful.

Comment: (Although now I see that the comment to your previous questions containing that link was deleted in the meantime.)